# Woocommcerce - Remove the "Related products" tab

Tags: woocommerce

I'm having a hard time trying to remove the "Related products" tab completely from my website.
I have searched for a solution but I have not had any luck so far. I would really appreciate if someone out there had a solution for this :)

The tab that i want to remove is shown here, below the image on this website for example; http://reservedelpilleovn.dk/produkt/gloederoer-eltaender-10-mm-x-200-mm-400-watt-2/

Hoping someone has a solution! :)

Comment: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/remove-related-posts-output/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a function to your **functions.php** and hook into it via `woocommerce_related_products_args`:

```
function wc_remove_related_products_tab( $args ) {
    return array();
}
add_filter('woocommerce_related_products_args','wc_remove_related_products_tab', 10);
```